Problems Syncing from Visual Studio Code to Github
I was trying to sync my changes to a website I'm making for a class, when this error came up:

unable to rewind rpc post data try increasing http.postBuffer.

I followed some advice from This StackOverflow Article and opened my command prompt and entered
 git config --global http.postBuffer 2097152000
 git config --global https.postBuffer 2097152000

Per the advice. Now, I'm getting a new error:

error: RPC failed; curl 55 OpenSSL SSL_read: OpenSSL/3.2.2: error:0A0003FC:SSL routines::ssl/tls alert bad record mac, errno 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

This is from the Command Output. I wonder if my original problem came because I accidentally put an executable file in one of the folders that are in my GitHub repository or something, but I don't know, I'm relatively new to all of this and I'm at my wits end...
As stated above, I tried the
 git config --global http.postBuffer 2097152000
 git config --global https.postBuffer 2097152000

Which brought up the current error I'm experiencing now. I'm not sure what I did, if I need to somehow unlink my git and link it back to VS, or however that works...
Edit:  I've tried to increase the buffer again per This Article that was helpfully suggested, and it's still spitting out the same error...

If you have not found a solution, I suggest you start over by making a new repoistory and copying the files into it.
